# Encode password easyadmin v3

Tags: passwords, symfony5, easyadmin

I have my user that I can manage from my administration panel, I can change the password, but the problem is that in the database it is not encrypted. It is in clear in the database, Save you how I could do it so that it is not anymore? I give you my user entity as well as the crud user And I use the easyadmin v3 and symfony 5 bundle.

My entity User

```html
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $prenom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $telephone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $aPropos;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $facebook;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Realisation::class, mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $realisations;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->realisations = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returning a salt is only needed, if you are not using a modern
     * hashing algorithm (e.g. bcrypt or sodium) in your security.yaml.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt(): ?string
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getPrenom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prenom;
    }

    public function setPrenom(string $prenom): self
    {
        $this->prenom = $prenom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTelephone(): ?string
    {
        return $this->telephone;
    }

    public function setTelephone(string $telephone): self
    {
        $this->telephone = $telephone;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAPropos(): ?string
    {
        return $this->aPropos;
    }

    public function setAPropos(?string $aPropos): self
    {
        $this->aPropos = $aPropos;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFacebook(): ?string
    {
        return $this->facebook;
    }

    public function setFacebook(?string $facebook): self
    {
        $this->facebook = $facebook;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Realisation[]
     */
    public function getRealisations(): Collection
    {
        return $this->realisations;
    }

    public function addRealisation(Realisation $realisation): self
    {
        if (!$this->realisations->contains($realisation)) {
            $this->realisations[] = $realisation;
            $realisation->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeRealisation(Realisation $realisation): self
    {
        if ($this->realisations->removeElement($realisation)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($realisation->getUser() === $this) {
                $realisation->setUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }
    /* public function __toString(){
         return $this->nom;
     }*/
}
```

```html
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\User;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\IntegerField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField;

class UserCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return User::class;
    }


    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            IntegerField::new('id','ID')->onlyOnIndex(),
            TextField::new('email'),
            TextField::new('password'),
            TextField::new('nom'),
            TextField::new('telephone'),
            TextField::new('aPropos'),
            TextField::new('facebook'),
        ];
    }


}
```

Answer (score 4):

This could be helpful ...

```
<?php

namespace App\Event\Subscriber;

use App\Entity\BackendUser;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Event\BeforeEntityUpdatedEvent;

class EasyAdminHooksSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    /**
     * @var UserPasswordEncoderInterface
     */
    private $passwordEncoder;

    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * EasyAdminSubscriber constructor.
     *
     * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     */
    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder, ContainerInterface $container) {
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array {
        return array(
            BeforeEntityUpdatedEvent::class => array('preUpdateEntity')
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param BeforeEntityUpdatedEvent $event
     *
     * @noinspection PhpUnused
     */
    public function preUpdateEntity(BeforeEntityUpdatedEvent $event) {
        $entity = $event->getEntityInstance();

        if($entity instanceof BackendUser) {
            $this->preUpdateBackendUser($entity);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param BackendUser $be_user
     */
    private function preUpdateBackendUser(BackendUser &$be_user) {
        $plain_password = $be_user->getPlainPassword();

        if(!empty($plain_password)) {
            $new_password = $this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword($be_user, $plain_password);
            $be_user->setPassword($new_password);
            $be_user->setPlainPassword();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to add this to your (Backend-)User class:

`   /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $plainPassword; `

Comment: So I have to create an Events folder, make a Subscriber file, and put the code you offer me then I have to add the code in my backend and my password will return to my database in encrypted form ?

Comment: If you want to put it in the events folder, make the namespace namespace App\Event; instead of namespace App\Event\Subscriber; - got this error myself, otherwise it works.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but this answer seems like a very convoluted way... Can we consider an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [solution](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/3349#issuecomment-695214741) I found while trying to create/edit users from my web app's admin dashboard (Symfony 5.3 and EasyAdmin v3). I found it in the EasyAdmin issue tracker over on Github.

You will need to add a plain password field to you User class and set the appropriate getter & setter methods.

```php
/**
 * @var string
 */
private $plainPassword;

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getPlainPassword(): string
{
    return $this->plainPassword;
}
```

Add event listeners to listen to create/edit form submission events, extract the plain password from the submitted form data and then hash it.

```php
/** @var UserPasswordHasherInterface */
private $hasher;

public function createEditFormBuilder(EntityDto $entityDto, KeyValueStore $keyValueStore, AdminContext $context): FormBuilderInterface
{
    $formBuilder = parent::createEditFormBuilder($entityDto, $keyValueStore, $context);
    $this->addEncodePasswordEventListener($formBuilder);

    return $formBuilder;
}

public function createNewFormBuilder(EntityDto $entityDto, KeyValueStore $formOptions, AdminContext $context): FormBuilderInterface
{
    $formBuilder = parent::createNewFormBuilder($entityDto, $formOptions, $context);
    $this->addEncodePasswordEventListener($formBuilder);

    return $formBuilder;
}

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $formBuilder
 */
public function addEncodePasswordEventListener(FormBuilderInterface $formBuilder)
{
    $formBuilder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event){
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $event->getData();
        if ($user->getPlainPassword()) {
            $user->setPassword($this->hasher->hashPassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword()));
        }
    });

}
```

Then finally you need to render the appropriate form fields.

```php
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    return [
        # other fields
        Field::new('plainPassword', 'New Password')->onlyOnForms()
        ->setFormType(RepeatedType::class)
        ->setFormTypeOptions([
               'type' => PasswordType::class,
               'first_options' => ['label' => 'New password'],
               'second_options' => ['label' => 'Repeat Password']
        ])->setRequired(true)
    ];
}
```

Hope someone finds this useful.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. Works in SF6 - I needed to add the hasher to the constructor and setPassword() method to the code sample. With those two modifications, This code sample worked straight off the bat. Thank you for putting in the effort @Japohidev.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm really glad that you found the answer useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can add plain password field in User entity:

```
private ?string $plainPassword= '';
public function getPlainPassword(): ?string
{
    return $this->plainPassword;
}

public function setPlainPassword(?string $plainPassword): void
{
    $this->plainPassword = $plainPassword;
}
```

Add password updater in User repo:

```
public function setNewPassword(PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface $user, string $plainPassword): void
{

    $hashedPassword = $this->hasher->hashPassword($user, $plainPassword);
    $user->setPassword($hashedPassword);
    $this->_em->persist($user);
    $this->_em->flush();
}
```

And override update/persist methods In UserCrudController:

```
public function updateEntity(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, $entityInstance): void
{
    $this->updatePassword($entityInstance);
    parent::updateEntity($entityManager, $entityInstance);
}

public function persistEntity(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, $entityInstance): void
{
    $this->updatePassword($entityInstance);
    parent::persistEntity($entityManager, $entityInstance);
}

private function updatePassword(User $user): void
{
    if ($user->getPlainPassword() == '') return;
    $this->userRepository->setNewPassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
}
```

It's work in Symfony 5.4.2 / EasyAdmin 3.5.19

Comment: Is used this concept, but put the setNewPassword() method into an already existing UserFactory Service. Works just fine.